# select_for_update blocks forever

Tags: django, postgresql, django-1.10

When I use `select_for_update` on a particular key, the call never returns.

A regular select works:

```
MyModel.objects.get(pk=pk_1) # Works
```

But `select_for_update` doesn't:

```
with transaction.atomic():
    MyModel.objects.select_for_update().get(pk=pk_1) # Blocks forever
```

If I change `pk_1` to another key, it works. I am not sure why the row would be locked. There are no other connections to the database (to be certain of this I have reset all machines with database access, but the call still blocks for this particular key).

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Did show processlist in database? Maybe this row is locked by another connection

Comment: @Guinner `select * from pg_stat_activity;` doesn't show any other connections.

Comment: Does `pg_stat_activity` say your session is waiting on a lock? What's in `pg_locks`? Anything in `pg_prepared_xacts`?

Comment: @Flash How's it going?

Comment: @Guinner I revisited this problem after a few days and the lock appears to be released, so not sure what to do with this question (I am not sure what caused the problem, or if it will happen again).